# Django import-export exclude not working

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-import-export

I've been working with Django import-export so that I can get csv files from my database. These csv files have some fields that aren't relevant since they are changed when items are put into the database and thus I dont want them in the table.

I have followed the docs for import-export but can't seem to exclude these fields properly. in my admin.py file I have:

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class ArtAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'category', 'type', 'agent', 'authenticate', ]
    search_fields = ('name', 'category', 'artist', 'id', 'authenticate', )
    list_filter = ["authenticate"]
    actions = [approve_art, reject_art]

class ArtResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Art
        exclude = ('authenticate', )
```

When I go into python manage.py shell and get it to print out the csv it is how I expect it to be, however when I use python manage.py runserver and then export it I will still see the authenticate column, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you forgot to link the resource class with you modeladmin

```
class ArtResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Art
        exclude = ('authenticate', )

    class ArtAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = ArtResource

    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'category', 'type', 'agent', 'authenticate', ]
    search_fields = ('name', 'category', 'artist', 'id', 'authenticate', )
    list_filter = ["authenticate"]
    actions = [approve_art, reject_art]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it! Quick question... With the import section of it it asks for all of the fields in the correct order, since some will be overwritten when put into the database there is no point in having them in it so do you know if there is a way to exclude some input fields?

Comment: using exclude will do it even for import

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ArtAdmin` and `resource_class = ArtResource` are indented an extra level. Was that a typo?